# Styling Sherlock Action Bar drop down items

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, styles, actionbarsherlock

I've been trying for a while to style the items in a drop down list I added to the Action Bar, but I can't come up with the right code.

I tried looking into the `abs__styles.xml` and `abs__themes.xml` in the `SherlockActionBar` project but none of the items I added to my project worked.

The way I'm creating the menus is the following:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Sharing icons
        SubMenu submenu = menu.addSubMenu(null);
        submenu.add(getResources().getString(R.string.twitter));
        submenu.add(getResources().getString(R.string.facebook));
        submenu.add(getResources().getString(R.string.email));

        // Share button itself
        MenuItem ShareButton = submenu.getItem();
        ShareButton.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_share_triangle);
        ShareButton.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        // Twitter submenu button
        MenuItem TwitterItem = submenu.getItem(0);
        TwitterItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
        TwitterItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                setShareTwitterIntent();
                return true;
            }
        });
...
}
```

I also tried taking a look at this [post](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) using the following code, but still no luck:

```
<!-- style the list navigation -->
<style name="MyDropDownNav" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ad_spinner_background_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/ad_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/ad_selectable_background</item>
</style>
```

I just need to change the background color of the items in the drop down list.

Thanks a lot for your help!

EDIT:

I also tried this, and it still doesn't work:

```
<item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyApp.DropDownNav</item>
<item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyApp.DropDownNav</item>
...
<style name="MyApp.DropDownNav" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/sharing_panel</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Is your custom theme deriving from Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar?

Comment: Did you get your problem solved?

Comment: this got postponed in my project since it was low priority, but as soon as I fix it, I'll let you guys know..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same problem and after a lot of head scratching - the sort of scratching like a dog with a bad case of fleas - I got it to work. This is with ABS 4.1 (90). The below code will change the background colour of the drop down item.

SomeActivity.java

```
Context context = ab.getThemedContext();
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    context, R.array.map_activity_view_list,
    R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Note: You use R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item for the createFromResource and R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item for the setDropDownViewResource.
This is what appears in the sample in the ABS source: 
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/ListNavigation.java

This is because the unselected dropdown in the action bar when is the sherlock_spinner_item layout and the actual dropdown items use the sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item layout which means the styles are different for each:

- sherlock_spinner_item

  - android:spinnerItemStyle
  - spinnerItemStyle
- sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item

  - android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle
  - spinnerDropDownItemStyle

Remember both styles are needed - android: prefixed styles for for the native ICS ActionBar and the style without the android: prefix is for the AcrionBarSherlock style on devices older than ICS.

res/values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <!--  the text when loading -->
        <!--
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
        -->

        <!-- the dropdown items -->
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/MyApp.Widget.Holo.DropDownItem</item>
        <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/MyApp.Widget.Holo.DropDownItem</item>

        <!--  the action bar dropdown menu item -->
        <!-- 
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/MyApp.Widget.Holo.SpinnerItem</item>
        <item name="spinnerItemStyle">@style/MyApp.Widget.Holo.SpinnerItem</item>
        -->
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

   <style name="Widget.MyApp.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/orange</item>
    </style>

   <style name="MyApp.Widget.Holo.DropDownItem" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner">
       <item name="android:background">@color/orange</item>
    </style>

   <style name="MyApp.Widget.Holo.SpinnerItem" parent="Widget.Sherlock.TextView.SpinnerItem">
       <item name="android:background">@color/orange</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

res/values/color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

 <color name="orange">#ffEf4f1f</color>

</resources>
```

Please mark as answer if this solves it for you. Thanks!

Links:

Browse styles:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/res/values/abs__styles.xml

Browse themes:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/res/values/abs__themes.xml

Comment: no it doesn't work like you said. Nevertheless I updated my post showing how I create the menu.

Comment: Strange, it worked for me in my project. Perhaps there are other changes in your styles/themes that are affecting it.

Comment: The key for me was using the getThemedContext() instead of just passing the activity. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To change the background drawable of the menu item in Sherlock Action Bar (v4.1.0), use the following:

```
<style name="My_Theme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
  <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyApp.PopupMenuStyle</item>
  <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyApp.PopupMenuStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyApp.PopupMenuStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ListPopupWindow">
  <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_item_background</item>
</style>
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

i used this, and its work for me

```
<style name="MyDropDownItem" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/actionbar_normal</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="myTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownItem</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownItem</item>
</style>
```

where,

"spinner_background_holo_light" and "list_selector_holo_light" are selectors

and

"actionbar_normal" drawable (image OR color)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this question has been answered in a satisfactory way, but I ran into this problem and did not find an answer that I liked.  It seemed like I had a pretty standard configuration of ActionBarSherLock and using the drop down navigation gave me some bad results out of the box.  Black text on a black background.  I want to make the text white.  Here is how I accomplished it:

For starters, my application's base theme extends Theme.Sherlock:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
</style>
```

My actual application theme AppTheme extends my base (I can't remember why I did this at the time, it is likely unnecessary).

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemStyle</item>
</style>
```

I needed to override `Widget.Sherlock.TextView.SpinnerItem` and so as below:

```
<style name="SpinnerItemStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.TextView.SpinnerItem">
<item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.MySpinnerItem</item>
</style>
```

The reason for doing this was to access the TextApperance widget: `TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem`

This was overridden as below:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.MySpinnerItem"    parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
  <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

My biggest mistake in tying to get the text in trying to fix this was trying to directly set textColor in the overridden SpinnerItemStyle.  Since it used a textAppearance widget, it was just not working.

Then my code to make this work looks like this (in my activity's onCreate method):

```
SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.call_type, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);

OnNavigationListener onNavigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {
        // Get the same strings provided for the drop-down's ArrayAdapter
        String[] strings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.call_type);

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId) {
            String filter = strings[position];
            filterCalls(filter);
            return true;
        }
    };

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(spinnerAdapter,
            onNavigationListener);
```

This allowed my to change the color of the text, on the spinner drop down using ActionBarSherlock.

Answer (score 0):

ActionBarSherlock requires you to use one of its 3 themes. You can extend them though, and override the dropdown style, like this:

```
<style name="MySherlockLightTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
   <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
</style>
```

This is assuming you want the holo light theme, and your dropdown style is MyDropDownDav.

Then in your code, you just switch to use your theme (either in the manifest, or do it in Activity's onCreate).

Comment: Make sure you also put `<item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>` so that the native action bar will use it as well on honeycomb and later.

Comment: I did a <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light"><item name="actionDropDownStyle">@drawable/sharing_panel_correct</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@drawable/sharing_panel_correct</item></style> but it still doesn't work, no differences..