# Actionbar submenu item background

Tags: android, menu, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBar sherlock library in my application
how to change the ActionBar SUBMENU list item background what is attribute i should use in styles?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you will want to customise your `MenuItem`'s style by having the `android:itemBackground` attribute overridden with your custom `color/drawable selector` in your `style.xml`.

In case your menu has also `submenu's`, then you will want as well to style the `header` title of the submenu, which usually is automatically with White background by overriding the attribute `actionBarPopupTheme` with your `custom style`.

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/menu_popup_selector</item>
        <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/SubmenuHeaderStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SubmenuHeaderStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**menu_popup_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color
            android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <color
            android:color="#655611"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And you will have something like this screenshot[image: screenshot of a menu with submenu] (the pink header is my submenu header).

Just for you to know when I have the normal *menu without submenu* would look like this hierarchy views:

```
<menu> 
   <item/>
   <item/> 
   <item/> 
</menu>
```

and a *menu with submenu* as this example of hierarchy views:

```
<menu> 
   <item/>
   <item/>
   <group> 
     <item> 
       <menu> 
         item 
         item 
         item 
       </menu> 
     </item>
   </group>
   <item/>
   <item/> 
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396772/styling-sherlock-action-bar-drop-down-items) shows you how to style the ABS drop down items. You can start by looking at res/values/styles.xml and changing the dropdown items style.

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <!--  the text when loading -->
    <!--
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
    -->

    <!-- the dropdown items -->
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/MyApp.Widget.Holo.DropDownItem</item>
    <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/MyApp.Widget.Holo.DropDownItem</item>

    <!--  the action bar dropdown menu item -->
    <!-- 
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/MyApp.Widget.Holo.SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="spinnerItemStyle">@style/MyApp.Widget.Holo.SpinnerItem</item>
    -->
</style>
```